# Allocating memory in Erlang C NIF

Tags: c, erlang, alloc, erlang-nif

Why would one use

```
void *enif_alloc_resource(ErlNifResourceType* type, unsigned size)
```

as opposed to

```
void *enif_alloc(size_t size)
```

when trying to allocate memory from an Erlang C NIF?

Reference does not specify much as to why.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_alloc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`enif_alloc_resource` is used to create resources which are garbage collected by the VM when not used any more. `enif_alloc` works just like `malloc`, only is uses an Erlang VM specific implementation rather than the OSs `malloc`. Take a look at the documentation for `ErlNifResourceType` and the functions which use it for some more details.

Comment: What is the difference in GC when using enif_alloc, is it only GC'd when I free it?

Comment: The gc is not involved at all when using enif_alloc. If you want GC you should use resources, if you will manage the life cycle of the memory yourself use enif_alloc and enif_free.