# Why use enif_alloc instead of malloc

Tags: c, erlang, malloc

Why would one use

void *enif_alloc(size_t size)
as opposed to

void *malloc(size_t size);
when trying to allocate memory from an Erlang C NIF?

Reference does not specify much as to why.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_alloc

I have seen NIF examples were malloc is used and I never see the enif_alloc.  What does it do differently?  Why is it better to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allocating memory in Erlang C NIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420970/allocating-memory-in-erlang-c-nif)

Comment: Its shocking to see he is the OP of this question too. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420970/allocating-memory-in-erlang-c-nif

Comment: It's a different question, and there is little available to piece together an answer.

Comment: @Sibrajas And what's the problem with that? It is not a duplicate. And it is better to write one post per question, instead of writing one "super post" with several, possibly unrelated questions in one post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`enif_alloc` uses the internal erlang memory allocators, which means that if the memory already is available in the internal VM cache it can use that memory instead of doing a system call to get the memory. This can lead to faster memory allocation in some cases, you will have to measure with your code to figure out if it makes any difference. In general I would recommend using `enif_alloc`.

If I remember correctly using `enif_alloc` also makes the memory used be included when issuing the `erlang:memory` command.

Comment: Perfect reason just what I was looking for.  Now exactly how do you know this?? Where can I look to learn?

Comment: This particular piece of info comes from reading erts_alloc, erl_nif man pages and the corresponding source code. You also have to understand how memory allocators in general work :)